# How to slow the rate at which light sensor listens?

Tags: java, android

I want to limit the frequency at which light sensor detects light, to save battery power and CPU usage.

After reading SO as well as trying it myself, I've found that changing the parameters of the `registerListener` method does nothing.

So next bet I guess is to make it sleep or wait every time the sensor senses light? How would I do that? I tried just putting `wait(2000);` inside it but that gives an error.

Here's the light sensor code:

```
SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

Sensor light = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

SensorEventListener listener = new SensorEventListener() {

          @Override
          public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                        
          }

          @Override
          public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                //Here is where I want to do my stuff   
          }

};

sm.registerListener(listener, light, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Comment: I see that you say that changing the parameters of `registerListener()` doesn't do anything, but I want to double-check that you realize that the units for the third argument are microseconds, not milliseconds. The doc _does_ say that the system is free to deliver events faster than specified, but perhaps you just need to increase the value you're passing if you were using the wrong units.

Comment: First time I just tried the value 1000000 it didn't work. Then I kept adding zeros and tried again each time. It never worked. Sensor still picks up values like every millisecond.

Comment: @Ben P. I saw there's a way that uses `handler.postDelayed` but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Comment: @Ben P. Please I need an answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Do your stuff at minimum interval:

```
    private final long minimumInterval = 100;
    private long lastRefresh;

    SensorEventListener listener = new SensorEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            long timeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (lastRefresh - timeMillis > minimumInterval) {
                lastRefresh = timeMillis;
                //do stuff
            }
        }

    };
```

Comment: I saw something like this somewhere else but didn't use it because it doesn't save battery life since the onSensorChanged method keeps getting called every millisecond. Is there a way to use `handler.postDelayed` to pause the listener?

Comment: No when registerListener(listener, light, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) not works, I think  that, is  device/soft problem or both